# Is it possible to debug an R Markdown chunk using "print()" to see certain variables on console?

Tags: r, r-markdown, chunks

In R Markdown I'm getting the following error:

```
  |......................................................................| 100%
label: heatmap_placement (with options)
List of 2
 $ echo   : logi TRUE
 $ results: chr "asis"

Quitting from lines 176-230 (summary_report_v03.Rmd)
Error in readChar(con, 5L, useBytes = TRUE) : cannot open the connection
Calls: hmp2rep ... withCallingHandlers -> withVisible -> eval -> eval -> load -> readChar
```

It looks like I'm getting this error because it cannot open some file inside a chunk of R code (it's a large piece of code with some nested for-loops).

To debug I use to place some "print()" functions to check some variables and see what's wrong on screen. But, since the bug is inside a chunk, I can't see anything.

Is it possible to debug Rmd chunks using "print()" functions to see what's happening inside? Otherwise, what can I do to guess where the bug is?

Comment: Based on the error you've gotten, I'm guessing that it can't find an external file. Keep in mind that RMD doesn't consider the directory you set in R. The current directory when you knit is the folder the RMD is saved in.

Comment: After some trials, it seems it's not possible to show anything. Instead of ```print()```, I used ```debug(variable_name)```. This is a **wrong** way to check a variable, since ```debug()``` is expecting a function as an argument, but it showed the content of the variable as part of an error message. This was enough to locate my bug (a misspelled file name).

Comment: @quesadagranja:  You shouldn't conclude something is impossible just because you can't figure out how to do it.  See my answer:  there are (at least) a couple of ways to display messages from RMarkdown code in the console log.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it with `message()` if you set the chunk option not to include messages in the document.  For example,

````
```{r message=FALSE}
x <- runif(1)
message(x)
```
````

Another possibility is to set an unused chunk option to a string, e.g.

````
```{r chunkmsg=paste("x = ", x)}
y <- 1
```
````

Using both of these prints this to the console:

```
  |..................                                                    |  25%
  ordinary text without R code

  |...................................                                   |  50%
label: unnamed-chunk-1 (with options) 


processing file: Untitled.Rmd
List of 1
 $ message: logi FALSE

  |....................................................                  |  75%
  ordinary text without R code

  |......................................................................| 100%
label: unnamed-chunk-2 (with options) 
List of 1
 $ chunkmsg: chr "x =  0.287577520124614"


0.287577520124614
output file: Untitled.knit.md

/Applications/RStudio.app/Contents/MacOS/pandoc/pandoc +RTS -K512m -RTS Untitled.knit.md --to html4 --from markdown+autolink_bare_uris+tex_math_single_backslash --output Untitled.html --lua-filter /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.1/Resources/library/rmarkdown/rmarkdown/lua/pagebreak.lua --lua-filter /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.1/Resources/library/rmarkdown/rmarkdown/lua/latex-div.lua --self-contained --variable bs3=TRUE --standalone --section-divs --template /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.1/Resources/library/rmarkdown/rmd/h/default.html --no-highlight --variable highlightjs=1 --variable theme=bootstrap --include-in-header /var/folders/d6/s97fjjxd3_9353x_lwb692100000gn/T//Rtmp4tTiD4/rmarkdown-str44473d4f8885.html --mathjax --variable 'mathjax-url:https://mathjax.rstudio.com/latest/MathJax.js?config=TeX-AMS-MML_HTMLorMML' 

Output created: Untitled.html
```

Notice that the `chunkmsg` string appears in the list of chunks, while the `message()` string appears after all of them.  In some cases the `message()` string will appear earlier; I think it depends on what is in the following chunks.